# joining two dataframes flagging missing information

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I would like to fill up missing cases in the `problem` dataframe in a way that for each missing id (3 in group 1 and 2 in group 2) I get a new line with the group # and and the id and NA for the target.

```
problem <- 
    data.frame(id = c(c(1,2,4,5),c(1,3,4,5)), group = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)), target = c(rep(c('A','B'),4)))

#id group target
#  1     1      A
#  2     1      B
#  4     1      A
#  5     1      B
#  1     2      A
#  3     2      B
#  4     2      A
#  5     2      B
```

with the id list from the `full` dataframe.

```
full <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5))

#id
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

desired result should be:

```
 #id group target
 # 1     1      A
 # 2     1      B
 # 3     1      NA
 # 4     1      A
 # 5     1      B
 # 1     2      A
 # 2     2      NA
 # 3     2      B
 # 4     2      A
 # 5     2      B
```

I went through all the joins I can think of but got stuck with `dplyr` and `tidyr` not really doing what I need.

Comment: `problem %>% complete(id, group)`

Comment: Or `problem %>% complete(group, id = seq(max(full$id)))`